# Show specific row from table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table **table1**

```
id | name | age | emailid
-------------------------------
1  | abc  | 24  | abc@gmail.com
2  | abc  | 35  | abc@gmail.com
3  | abc  | 23  | abc@gmail.com
```

**My php code is:**

```
<?php
require"connection.php";

$email=$_SESSION["email"];

$qry=mysql_query("select * from user_new_history where email='$email' order by id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while($qry1=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    if($count<1)
    {
        echo $id;
    }
}
?>
```

It gives last two rows. But I want to show only 2nd row.
How can it be possible ?

Please help.

Comment: Don't forget indentations in your code.

Comment: Since you haven't been clear with what you want, i have made up this SQL-statement that will give you what you want, but might not be exactly what you want. `$qry=mysql_query("select * from user_new_history where id='2'") or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 1):

You use email for find user and you have 3 user with same name and email.

You must set unique 'email' and 'name' field.

Then you can find users.

Comment: If ID is unique use id for find user. When you try find user by email, email must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Do it in SQL:

```
select * from user_new_history where email='$email' order by id ASC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
  require"connection.php";

  $email=$_SESSION["email"];

  $qry=mysql_query("select * from user_new_history where email='$email' order by id ASC") or die(mysql_error());
  $count = 1;
   while($qry1=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
   {
     if($count == 2)
     {
       echo $id;
     }
     $count ++;
   }
?>
```